# "No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available"

Tags: spring

I have not added cassandra template bean in my beandefinition class, but it works fine and gives me the required output while running, but while writing junit test class
it is throwing me a error "No bean named 'cassandraTemplate' available".

Why is this issue raising during running my junit test class.

This is my code:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("cassandra.properties")
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "...repository")

public class Beandef
 {

    @Autowired
    public Environment environment;

    CassandraClusterFactoryBean cluster = new CassandraClusterFactoryBean();

    @Bean(name = "clusterFactory")
    public CassandraClusterFactoryBean getCluster() {
        PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
        cluster.setContactPoints(environment.getProperty("cassandra.contactpoints"));
        cluster.setPoolingOptions(poolingOptions);
        cluster.setPort(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty("cassandra.port")));
        poolingOptions.setNewConnectionThreshold(HostDistance.LOCAL, 50);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("clusterFactory")
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean getSession() throws Exception {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster.getObject());
        session.setKeyspaceName(environment.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace"));
        session.setConverter(new MappingCassandraConverter(new CassandraMappingContextAware()));
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);

        return session;
    }
```

Comment: Can anybody help me to resolve this issue

Comment: It is almost impossible to help you to solved it without code, configuration etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Spring Boot, and if your test class doesn't have a @SpringBootApplication available in the classpath, you have to add @EnableAutoConfiguration to enable Spring Boot auto-config (even with spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra in your dependencies).